# Finding the zeros while also finding the y-intercept of two intersecting functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In this video I am viewing, we are asked to find the volume of a solid given two functions.  It says, "The base of a solid is the region enclosed by the graphs of $y=-x^2+6x-1$ and $y=4$. Express the volume of the solid with a definite integral." I have no issues integrating this problem, however my dilemma lies with what was done explained below.

The narrator points out the functions are equivalent. Thus:

$$-x^2+6x-1=4$$
$$-x^2+6x-5=0$$
$$x^2-6x+5=0$$
$$(x-5)(x-1)=0$$

Now the narrator states that $y=4$ when $x=1$ or $x=5$. I am a bit confused here. I know that when we have $x^2-6x+5=0$, setting $x=1$ or $x=5$ we get $y=4$. But why is it that these same values make $y=4$? Also I understand the logic of multiplying/dividing by $(-1)$, but doesn't that change the problem because in the original equation, $x=1$ and $x=5$ are not zeros.

Comment: "But why is it that these same values make y=4?". This statement is unclear. Clearly you are trying to find the intersection of the two curves and you found that to be the points (1,4) and (5,4). What's the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $f(x)= - x^2+6x-1$ and $g(x)=4$.

We want to figure out for which value of $x$ do we get $f(x)=g(x)$, that is when does $f(x)=4$.

We realized that $f(x)=4$ is equvalent to $(x-5)(x-1)=0$. That is any solution of $(x-5)(x-1)=0$ would make $f(x)=4$.

That is $f(1)=4$ and $f(5)=4$.